# PHP Добавление записи в бд через интервалы автоматически

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Мне нужно сохранить данные, получаемые из другого источника (не форма) в бд через определенное кол-во времени.

Первое решение, о котором я подумал - это при заходе пользователя на страничку запускать цикл, который это сделает, но тут есть проблемы:

- Пользователей на страничке может быть слишком много (но я не знаю, как хорошо это будет работать)
- и пользователей может вовсе не быть (ночью к примеру, соответственно данные добавляться не будут)

Второе, о чем я подумал - это постоянное исполнение скрипта php на сервере, но погуглив, я не нашел четкого объяснения как это сделать, к тому же не могу понять, как это будет работать и будет ли серьезно нагружать сервер.

**Вопрос**: как собственно мне реализовать эту задачу?

Comment: Первый в утиль я думаю, а второй, если речь о `cron`, то да. Имеет место быть

Answer (score 2):

Самый распространеный и надежный способ это с помощью CRON.
Прочитать подробнее и прочую документацию можно [тут](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-cron) и [тут](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron). А также советую поискать конкретные примеры под ваши задачи и идеи на использование связки CRON и PHP.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL имеет свой собственный планировщик. [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). Именно его следует использовать, а не городить костыли из внешних планировщиков и скриптов.

В нужное время и/или с нужной периодичностью (да хоть ежесекундно!) выполняется задание, которое собственно и осуществляет выполнение всех требуемых действий. И ему параллельно на всё, что происходит снаружи. Само собой, в выполняемой процедуре можно предусмотреть реакцию на любые внешние и внутренние обстоятельства.

Comment: Про это я читал, но так и не понял как мне сделать INSERT с нужными мне данными, а не подставленными изначально

Comment: @MrBlackLord *как мне сделать INSERT с нужными мне данными* А где они - эти нужные данные-то? Скрипт по-любому сам их не придумает, где-то они есть... вот оттуда скрипт их может взять.

Comment: Они парсятся с другого сайта, их мне нужно периодически сохранять в бд

Comment: @MrBlackLord *Они парсятся с другого сайта, их мне нужно периодически сохранять в бд* А вот чё бы парсеру прямо в БД не сливать? тогда никаких интервалов и планировщиков вообще не нужно... Ну или пусть в CSV сливает, а процедура планировщика их берёт - и в БД .